ui-select Dropdown Always Sends 'true' to Backend Regardless of Selection
I am working on an AngularJS project and have upgraded the library from ui-select2 to ui-select. I am specifically working on a dropdown, so I had the ui-select2 dropdown:
<select data-ui-select2="{allowClear: true}" ui-select2="clearDropDown" ng-model="isFinalSubmission" data-placeholder="Final Submission Done?" class="padding-left-right-zero">
   <option></option>
   <option value="true">Yes</option>
   <option value="false">No</option>    
</select>

I have now upgraded to ui-select dropdown:
<ui-select style="cursor: pointer;" ng-model="isFinalSubmission" theme="select2" 
class="padding-left-right-zero" search-enabled="true" 
ng-init="options = [{ value: 'true', label: 'Yes' },{ value: 'false' , label: 'No' }]">
   <ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="Final Submission Done?">{{$select.selected.label}}</ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices repeat="option.value as option in options | filter: $select.search">
      {{option.label}}
   </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>

<div class="col-sm-5">
   <br />
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" style="border-radius:5px" ng-d ng-click="loadGrid()">Search</button>
</div>

However, it is not working as expected. The dropdown value is displayed correctly when I click it, but when I perform an operation, the value sent to the backend is always the initial fixed value, which is not what I want.
Js File:
(function (window, angular, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('angularModule.controllers').controller('searchHoldingCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', '$window', 'ajaxCall', '$controller', 'checkPermissions', '$rootScope', '$location', 'permissionCheckService', 'fileDownloadService', 'holdingColumns','$timeout', function ($scope, $compile, $window, ajaxCall, $controller, checkPermissions, $rootScope, $location, permissionCheckService, fileDownloadService, holdingColumns, $timeout) {
        permissionCheckService.check('ETT_Reports_View');
        //Injecting common useful values to the scope
 $controller('commonCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
        $scope.selectIsinList();
        $scope.searchIsin = { Id: null };
        $scope.selectOptionsEmployeePromise();
        $scope.searchEmployee = { Id: null };
        $scope.searchTimePeriod = {}
        $scope.searchClass = {}
        $scope.searchParentCompany = {};
        $scope.copyHoldingToOpening = {};
        $scope.searchTimePeriodType = {};
        $scope.isFinalSubmission = true;
        $scope.isTimePeriodShow = false;
        $scope.isHoldingdateShow = false;
  $scope.loadGrid();
 $scope.loadGrid = function (reset) {
            $scope.reset = reset ? true : false;
            $scope.isGridIsShown = true;
            $scope.gridconfig.isLocalData = false;
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.$broadcast('LoadKendoGridEvent')
            })
        };
 $scope.ExportAnnualHoldingPDFReport = function () {

            var url = "/ETT/Reports/ExportAnnualHoldingPDFReport";
            var emp = isValidObject($scope.searchEmployee) ? $scope.searchEmployee.Id : null;
            var time = isValidObject($scope.searchTimePeriod) ? $scope.searchTimePeriod.Id : null;
            var holdingDate = isValidObject($scope.model.searchHoldingDate) ? $scope.model.searchHoldingDate : "";
            var timePeriodTypeId = isValidObject($scope.searchTimePeriodType) ? $scope.searchTimePeriodType.Id : null;
            var isin = isValidObject($scope.searchIsin) ? $scope.searchIsin.Id : null;
            var classId = isValidObject($scope.searchClass) ? $scope.searchClass.Id : null;
            var parentCompanyId = isValidObject($scope.searchParentCompany) ? $scope.searchParentCompany.Id : null;
            var isFinalSubmission = isValidObject($scope.isFinalSubmission) ? $scope.isFinalSubmission : null;
            $rootScope.viewLoading = true;

            fileDownloadService.downloadFilePost(url, JSON.stringify({
                emp: emp,
                timePeriod: time,
                holdingDate: holdingDate,
                timePeriodTypeId: timePeriodTypeId,
                isin: isin,
                classId: classId,
                parentCompanyId: parentCompanyId,
                isFinalSubmission: isFinalSubmission
            })).then(function (data) {
                if (!angular.isUndefined(data) && data.IsError == true) {
                    alertify.error(data.Message);
                    $rootScope.viewLoading = false;
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    $rootScope.viewLoading = false;
                }
            });
        }

        //Search
        $scope.gridconfig.getData = function (e) {
            $scope.gridconfig.isLocalData = true;
            $scope.model.RowsPerPage = $scope.reset ? 20 : e.data.pageSize;
            $scope.model.PageNumber = $scope.reset ? 1 : e.data.page;

            var emp = $scope.searchEmployee == undefined ? null : $scope.searchEmployee.Id;
            var time = $scope.searchTimePeriod == undefined ? null : $scope.searchTimePeriod.Id;
            var holdingDate = $scope.model.searchHoldingDate == undefined ? "" : $scope.model.searchHoldingDate;
            var timePeriodTypeId = $scope.searchTimePeriodType == undefined ? null : $scope.searchTimePeriodType.Id;
            var isin = $scope.searchIsin == undefined ? null : $scope.searchIsin.Id;
            var classId = $scope.searchClass == undefined ? null : $scope.searchClass.Id;
            var parentCompanyId = $scope.searchParentCompany == undefined ? null : $scope.searchParentCompany.Id;
            var isFinalSubmission = $scope.isFinalSubmission == undefined ? null : $scope.isFinalSubmission;
            $rootScope.viewLoading = true;
            ajaxCall.get('/ETT/Reports/SearchHoldings?emp=' + emp + '&timePeriod=' + time + '&holdingDate=' + holdingDate + '&timePeriodTypeId=' + timePeriodTypeId + '&isin=' + isin + '&classId=' + classId +
                '&parentCompanyId=' + parentCompanyId + '&isFinalSubmission=' + isFinalSubmission).then(function (data) {

                    if (angular.isUndefined(data) && data == null) {
                        $scope.holdingDataSource = [];
                        return;
                    }
                    if (!data.IsError) {
                        $scope.holdingDataSource = data.SearchResults;

                        $scope.gridconfig.ds = getRecordsForPage($scope.holdingDataSource, $scope.model.PageNumber, $scope.model.RowsPerPage);
                        $scope.gridconfig.dataCount = $scope.holdingDataSource.length;
                        e.success({ data: $scope.gridconfig.ds, total: $scope.gridconfig.dataCount });
                        $rootScope.viewLoading = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        alertify.error(data.Message)
                        $rootScope.viewLoading = false;
                    }
                });
        };

    }]);
})(window, window.angular);

What I Have Tried:

Checked the ui-select documentation to ensure proper configuration.
Verified that isFinalSubmission contains the expected data.

Issue:
It shows "true" in the backend even when "No" is selected.
Expected Behavior:
The dropdown should correctly reflect the selected option and send the appropriate value to the backend.

when is sent this value ? in the call of downloadFilePost ?

The issue is not related to the downloadFilePost call. The problem is that when I select an option from the dropdown, the backend always receives "true" regardless of the actual selection. The dropdown should display the correct records based on the selected value.

my question was to know when is the value isFinalSubmission send to backend ?

The value of isFinalSubmission is sent to the backend when a form is submitted or when a specific action triggers a backend call.

and which code send this value ?

The value of isFinalSubmission is sent to the backend when the user performs a specific action, such as clicking a button. In this case, the value is sent when the loadGrid function is called, which is triggered by the click event on the "Search" button.
